# How to force content to overflow horizontally in CSS?

Tags: css

Is there any way to make the content to flow to left/right instead of down while the container doesn't have enough space for it in CSS?

```css
.container1 {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
}

.container2 {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}

.content {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.overflowContent {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}


/* You can add background colors to see where every part is */
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="content">First half</div>
  <div class="content">Second half</div>
  <div class="overflowContent">Overflow</div>
</div>
<div class="container2"></div>
```

I want a way that makes the overflow part go on the right side of the container instead of below it.(i want the third part to be displayed on/over the container 2)
My idea was to add something to a link with [ display : hidden ] that only shows up [ display : block ] on the right side of the link on the other parts of the website while we hover on the link.

Comment: (50+50)% would take up the whole row. The overflow isn't going to fit in that row until you decrease the width of  the other two columns.

Comment: You can also place the div outside the container to see it on the right.

Comment: What do you mean "go on the right side"?

Comment: Yes but I want my third part to be shown ON the other parts of the website, i dont want it to take any space for itself (I edited the post so you know what i mean easier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this considering `inline-block` and `white-space:nowrap`. Don't forget to reset the whitespace between inline element (I used the font-size trick here)

```css
.container1 {
  width: 70%;
  display:inline-block;
  outline:1px solid red;
}

.container2 {
  width: 30%;
  display:inline-block;
  outline:1px solid green;
}

.content {
  width: 50%;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:initial;
}

.overflowContent {
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:initial;
}


body {
  font-size:0;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="content">First half</div>
  <div class="content">Second half</div>
  <div class="overflowContent">Overflow</div>
</div>
<div class="container2"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a div inside the container that will hold the overflowing content, and apply `overflow-x: auto` to the container.

The flexbox code is just a friendly suggestion, much easier to work with than floats for layout.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.container {
  width: 70%; 
  border: 5px solid red;
  overflow-x: auto; /* this causes anything inside that is wider to overflow horizontally */
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  background: papayawhip;
}

.overflowContent {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  padding: 20px;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="content">First half</div>
    <div class="content">Second half</div>
    <div class="overflowContent">Overflow</div>
  </div>
</div>
```